# Does siftware updater update only the current version of Ubuntu on the machine?

Tags: update-manager

I have two versions of Ubuntu on my machine. 16.04 and 20.04. They reside on separate discs. I can chose which version I want at startup by changing the boot sequence.

I booted to the 16.04 version and the software updater had updates waiting to be processed.

Can I be sure that these updates are for the 16.04 version only?

Comment: I see the potential in a related question: "How can I update both Ubuntu instances installed on my machine, while booting up only one of them?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

The key is whichever version you have booted.

When the software updater presents itself on the screen of the booted OS, that software updater belongs to the actively running OS, therefore it will take care of only that one.